# Java enumerations support methods? But not in c#?

Tags: c#, java, enumeration

I'm looking at this code of the correct way to do a singleton in java: [What is an efficient way to implement a singleton pattern in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/efficient-way-to-implement-singleton-pattern-in-java/71399#71399)

I'm a little confused, how do you add a method to a enumeration?

```
 public enum Elvis {
       INSTANCE;
       private final String[] favoriteSongs =
           { "Hound Dog", "Heartbreak Hotel" };
       public void printFavorites() {
           System.out.println(Arrays.toString(favoriteSongs));
       }
   }
```

And the enumeration in the code above, doesn't even make sense to me, you have the symbol:

```
INSTANCE;
```

how is that a correct line?

I'm coming from c#, and this syntax got me curious and I'm hoping someone can explain or make sense of the above.

I guess it means java has a more purer idea of an enumeration as it can have behaviour?

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: If you're asking "why does that syntax work in Java?", it's because whoever designed enums in Java decided so.

Comment: Btw, for some interpretations of "add a method to an enum", extension methods may help

Comment: Your example looks to me like a hackish Java workaround for the C# equivalent of a `struct`.  Looking through the pages in the link you've provided, it looks like this is done for memory efficiency.  But, one huge thing you have to consider is maintainability.  In 3 years, is a developer going to look at that code and understand, or silent wish all the perils of the world on your head?

Comment: @JimSchubert - using an enum as the basis for a singleton is java is pretty much the best way to do it.

Comment: @Inerdia, No he/she is not asking it. He/she tries to understand `enum` in Java since it is much different than c#

Comment: @JimSchubert The example is of the "proper" way to implement a singleton object in Java. Using an `Enum` over a `Class` guarantees that only one instance will ever be created and since, in Java, an `Enum` is a `Class`, you can have all the same functions/variables you'd attach to that class. `Struct`s in C# are not, by default, singletons. It's just as maintainable as a class with proper documentation on the final produce and documenting the choice of `Enum` over `Class`.

Comment: @izuriel Thanks for clarifying that. I am also a C# developer who has only done a little in Java, so this difference isn't readily apparent.   This also explains why some of the devs with Java backgrounds on my team think of C# `enum` types differently.

Comment: @JimSchubert I started with Java and have used it extensively but currently work at a place that only uses C# so I've run into the differences quite often :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An enum in Java is actually a class. One that implicitly extends java.lang.Enum. The special syntax you see at `INSTANCE;` is a declaration of an enum constant. This is going to be used to make an instance of your enum class which can be referred to in code. As a matter of fact, you can even have a non-default constructor for your enum and use it in the constant declaration. Example:

```
public enum Test {

    INSTANCE("testing");

    private final String content;
    public Test(final String content) {
        super();
        this.content = content;
    }

}
```

Treating enums as true objects has certain advantages. Putting some logic into enums is convenient, but shouldn't be abused either. The singleton pattern via enums is a nice solution in my opinion, though.

Comment: That's a good clean answer there. In short, think of a Java enum type a as regular class, which can have fields, constructor and methods, but which simply comes with a predefined set of instances.

Comment: @G_H is `INSTANCE` a special keyword in this situation, or can it be whatever you choose?

Comment: @JimSchubert You can pick whatever name adheres to the Java language specs. It doesn't have a special meaning here. It's standard practice to use names in upper case for enums, though. `INSTANCE` isn't a keyword in Java, nor is it in lower case. `instanceof` is, so that wouldn't be usable.

Answer (score 1):

To give a slightly different answer, and one that I think you're asking, the `INSTANCE;` line in the Java code is the equivalent line of `Instance` in the following C# example:

```
enum Elvis
{
    Instance
}
```

It's the way you create a `value` for a Java `enum`. To further the example a Java enum could be:

```
public enum Gender {
    MALE,
    FEMALE;
}
```

Where the value types are `Gender.MALE` and `Gender.FEMALE` which is equivalent to:

```
enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female
}
```

in C#.

If I have veered far from your question I apologize.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an extension method

```
enum Elvis
{
  Instance
}

static class ElvisExtension
{
  private static readonly string[] FavoriteSongs = { "Hound Dog", "Heartbreak Hotel" };

  public static void PrintFavorites(this Elvis singleton)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", FavoriteSongs));
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Elvis.Instance.PrintFavorites();
```